# Desktop wallpaper resets to default at every reboot in Sierra (10.12.1)

Tags: macos, desktop, wallpaper

Upon update to Sierra I'm finding that my wallpaper is set back to the default Sierra wallpaper at every reboot.  The correct wallpapers are selected in System Preferences, but they are not shown.  I find that I have to go into the wallpapers, select a new one and then immediately pick the desired one again.

This is annoying when you have several monitors attached and have to do this for each one at every reboot.

Any idea on how to resolve this?

Answer (score 2):

You probably don't need the answer anymore, but just in case anyone stumbles across this post some day:

I had the same problem under Sierra and solved it by unchecking the 'displays have separate spaces' option in mission control settings.

Comment: Funny enough the problem went away and then came back again in 10.13 and has not yet fully resolved itself. I've been talking to Apple for years on this issue, but they can't seem to really nail it down and keep telling me they know about the issue already. Further, unchecking that option's not an option for me as I work with multiple monitors and the behavior that occurs when displays have separate spaces is not desirable behavior. ‍♂️